# Why is this printing memory addresses instead of values

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix-multiplication

Here is my driver

```
int square[2][2] = {
    {1,2},
    {3,4}
};

matrixMulti(square, 2);
```

Here is my function

```
void matrixMulti(const int a[][2], const int rows) {

    int b[2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                b[i][j] += a[i][k] * a[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "new matrix " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout << b[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
new matrix
-858993453 -858993450
-858993445 -858993438
```

I am confused as to why it is printing the memory addresses rather then the values stored in them and what can be done to get it to print the values rather than the memory address.

Comment: [Turn on compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E89p2V)

Comment: It's not printing memory addresses -- however you are starting with uninitialized values in your `b[2][2]` array, so it's undefined what the results of the calculation will be.

Comment: `int b[2][2];` Did you mean `int b[2][2] = {};`?

Comment: Those aren't memory addresses. When you see a weird number like -858993450, convert it to hex and see if it is more recognizable as an error code. In this case we get CCCCCCD6 which is CCCCCCCC plus what you added. According to [a reputable list of common debugging codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values), CCCCCCCC is uninitialized stack memory

Comment: `b[i][j] += a[i][k] * a[k][j];` - you never *initialized* the members of `b`, so you are just adding values to garbage (elements with indeterminate value). That code has Undefined Behaviour. Your program is broken and has no meaning. In C++ values of an array are not magically initialized to zero. *You* have to do that (if needed) and you cannot just read uninitialised variables with well defined results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
int b[2][2];
```

and then

```
b[i][j] += ...
```

Where did you initialize b ?

```
int b[2][2] = {};
```

or

```
int b[2][2] = {0,0};
```

Should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage values are being printed, not the address of the array. 
Here is why.
In this snippet of code

```
void matrixMulti(const int a[][2], const int rows) {

    int b[2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                b[i][j] += a[i][k] * a[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

You allocated space for `int b[2][2]`, but you do not initialize it to a value. This would be fine except in the for-loop body. 
`b[i][j] += a[i][k] * a[k][j];` <=> `b[i][j] = b[i][j] + a[i][k] * a[k][j];`
you are referencing the value of `b[i][j]` before it is initialized. In other words you say `b[i][j]` is equal to `b[i][j] + a[i][k] * a[k][j]`, but you can't do this as, the value of `b[i][j]` is unknown.

The solution to this is to initialize `int b[2][2] = {{0,0},{0,0}};`

Comment: Maybe add a reference to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub and explain that reading uninitialised variables is UB..